# Is there a way to combine or merge Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

I have two distinct logins for this site. One I made a long time ago, then one more recently. I am actually not quite sure how it happened.

Is there any way to merge them?

Comment: Cross-meta dupe:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/175248

Answer (score 6):

Yes, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the contact form and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.